# Understanding hash Implementation and it's memory in Redis

Tags: memory, hash, redis, hashmap

From documentation we know redis does compression for data within a range (512 by default). If the hash ranges over 512 then the memory difference would be 10 times.

I did a small experiment for hashes ranging from 1 to 512 and found some interesting pattern.

This Graph represents Memory taken (in KB) for 1000 hashes each containing entries ranging from 1 to 512.

[image]

As you can see in this graph. There are steep in memory at certain intervals. I understand the hash implementation in redis also follows some logic for extending the size when it reaches a certain range and not increasing it for every new entry. From the numbers, it doesn't follow the doubling pattern throughout, but from 215 to 216 it does exactly double, 4 MB to 8 MB. From 420 to 421 it increases almost half 8 MB to 12 MB. In steeps within 215 I couldn't see any pattern it varies between 1/4th,1/5th and 1/6th.

With my observation following are my questions:

1. Can someone explain me about the internal happenings of hashmap in terms of memory and resizing? What is the logic followed during resizing?
2. If I have to loose double the memory just for storing one more entry that is 215 to 216, why can't I restrict my application to have a hashes less than 215 always, unless and until the system needs it at the most.
3. Suppose if I want to store 1 million hashes each consisting of 250 values I need 800MB. If I split them into 2 hashes of 125 values ie, 2 million hashes of 125 values I need 500MB. In this way I am saving 300 MB which is huge!!. Is this calcuation right? Am I missing something in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I know it's not relevant to this question, but have you tried set technique to reduce the data footprint?

Comment: @Karthikeyan Gopall，I think it's better if you provide two more details: 1. How you get the momery used? use redis-cli to get 'info Memory' and get the value of field ''used_memory" or "used_memory_rss" or somewhere else  2. You memory allocator which you can get by "./redis-cli  info |grep mem_allocator"

Comment: @sel-fish 1) I will get it from "used_memory". Before starting the process I will take the used_memory, after the process I will do the same and difference of them is what I have mentioned in the graph.

2) mem_allocator:jemalloc-3.6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have constantly 1000 keys in redis, only field number changes in each hash key, and you field number is lower than 512, so this phenomenon is only caused by jemalloc.

Here is the behavior as I use libc as my mem_allocator:

[image]

You can remake your redis by :

```
make MALLOC=libc
```

Run your test again, and see what you will get.

To answer your questions:

1. Can someone explain me about the internal happenings of hashmap in terms of memory and resizing? What is the logic followed during resizing?

   **As mentioned, what you encountered has nothing to do with redis itself. Jemalloc do it this way to improve its efficiency**
2. If I have to loose double the memory just for storing one more entry that is 215 to 216, why can't I restrict my application to have a hashes less than 215 always, unless and until the system needs it at the most.

   **Of course, you can do it as long as you can restrict the field numbers**
3. Suppose if I want to store 1 million hashes each consisting of 250 values I need 800MB. If I split them into 2 hashes of 125 values ie, 2 million hashes of 125 values I need 500MB. In this way I am saving 300 MB which is huge!!. Is this calcuation right? Am I missing something in this case?

   **I don't think that's a proper way to do that. Maybe you can save some memory by doing this. However, the disadvantages are: as you split 1 million hashes to 2 million, redis will do rehashing(which will take you some space) and it will take you more time to find one key, because it will leads to more chance of hash confliction.**

Comment: yes you are right. I have done the same process using libc and understood the difference. Thanks for sharing the knowledge :)

Comment: So glad that the answer helps. And thank you for bring me this question :)

Answer (score 4):

@sel-fish Got it right. It's all about the memory allocator. I would like to add few more information to that for the benefit of others.

I have done one more experiment comparing the time taken for doing the same operation in jemalloc and libc. I have done this two experiments in exactly under the same circumstance for better clarity. I couldn't find any major differences in the performance, libc wins most of the times.

I have attached the screenshots.

[image]

[image]

So as you can see in the graphs, jemalloc resizing is kinda double and libc is serially increasing.

And there is no major performance drop (time taken) by using libc. Actually libc takes less time in comparison in most of the areas.

I have also studied few articles about libc and jemalloc, In my point of view, For this scenario libc wins.

I would also like to hear from others on their point of view on the same.

Comment: I'm afraid that i have to ask a question unrelated to your answer, cant you please tell me what tool you used to draw the picture? or can you help me to answer the question here: http://superuser.com/questions/1090292/what-tool-is-used-to-draw-picture-below

Comment: @sel-fish That is an online BI tool called Zoho Reports (https://reports.zoho.com) . I will take time taken during the experiment, write them in CSV and then push them into the tool and have created the chart.

Answer (score 2):

Yoy may find full description of hash internals in article [Redis under the hood: Hash(part1)](http://redisplanet.com/redis/under-the-hood-of-redis-hash-part-1/) and [Redis under the hood: Hash(part2)](http://redisplanet.com/redis/under-the-hood-of-redis-hash-part-2-and-list/). In few words, memory grows a big each time:

1. You hash moves from `ziplist` to `dict` internal encoding.
2. You hash fill factor force Redis to double the size of hash.

Keep in mind - Redis uses `dict` to handle key space. So each time you are creating new key (of any type) you put it in the internal hash table of keys. So here is same logic - it grows as `dict` while you are adding new keys to Redis.

Comment: As @Karthikeyan Gopall said, in his experiment, there are 1000 hashes, which means there are always just 1000 keys in redis, so it has nothing to do with redis rehash. Further more, each hash has entries num less than 512, so every hash use ziplist.

Comment: Yes, but each time you are creating hash key (any type) you push it in internal hash table of keys. So here is same logic - redis internals hash which handle key spase grows.